# Do send/recv transfer data in identical chunks?

Tags: c, winsock, send, data-transfer, recv

From my client:

```
send(socket, "this is a buffer", ...);
send(socket, "second buffer", ...);
```

From my server, is `recv` guaranteed to end one chunk with the `r` from `"this is a buffer"` and begin another chunk with the `s` from `"second buffer'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not at all. You have no control over what happens when you receive the data due to all of the processing of the network. You can't make any assumption about how much you will get in any recv call (except for that it will be <= the amount sent). You could get as little as one byte.

Comment: What I mean is, in my example, will I ever receive (for example) `"a buffer\0second bu"`?

Comment: And if the answer is yes, how can I differentiate one 'packet' from another? Should I use some kind of termination sequence?

Comment: Yes, you could receive that as well. You will need to have something in the data to distinguish your 'packets'. You could have a convention where you send the length of the 'packet' or some kind of delimiter that will not be seen in the data.

Answer (score 0):

No, Windows sockets (like other TCP-based abstractions) are streaming. You are looking for a packetized way to use Windows sockets.

Try this:
http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/examples/packetize.html

Comment: More accurately, Windows TCP sockets are streaming.  UDP sockets are message-based instead. Each `send()` on a TCP socket just adds the data to the stream and there is no 1-to-1 relationship between `send()` and `recv()` on streams. Each `send()` on a UDP socket sends a distinct message, and there is a 1-to-1 relationship on messages.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rely on that. When reading, you might get them all at once. There are many things in between - packet reordering, network latency, etc, that influence when your packets actually arrive to the other side, and it might be that the second buffer might find its way through faster than the first and will wait (if you're using TCP, or not if not) for the first one to arrive. Then whatever arrived will be given to you. You should parse your data on the receiving side without relying on how it was sent (TCP provides you certain order assurances, UDP doesn't do that either).

Answer (score 0):

If you want recv to block until you have received a specified amount of bytes, you can use the flag MSG_WAITALL.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/recv.html

Answer (score 0):

For UDP and other datagram protocols, packet boundaries will be preserved like you want. For TCP and other stream protocols, no such luck.